# Postgresql: select field only if 2 fields are seperatly unique

Tags: postgresql

I need to select 10 unique locations, from where each location should be from a different user.
So the values in user_id and in location_id should both (seperatly) be unique.
Tried quite a few methods, but somehow it doesn't work out.

The query without caring about the uniques looks like:

```
SELECT
    b.user_id, 
    l.location_id,
    ROUND(distance(transform(PointFromText('POINT(4.0 52.0)', 4326), 26986),transform("spatialPoint", 26986))) AS distance
 FROM  locations AS l
    JOIN b_user_location AS b USING(location_id)
 ORDER BY ROUND(distance(transform(PointFromText('POINT(4.0 52.0)', 4326) ASC
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Seems i need something like:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT ON(user_id)
   DISTINCT ON(location_id)
   b.user_id,
   .....
```

But that is not allowed.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

[edit]
Link to SqlFiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7c090/2/0

Sql queries:

```
CREATE TABLE users (user_id SERIAL, username VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id));
CREATE TABLE locations(location_id SERIAL, "spatialPoint" INT,name VARCHAR(255),CONSTRAINT locations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (location_id));
CREATE TABLE b_user_location(user_id INT, location_id INT, CONSTRAINT user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),CONSTRAINT location_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY(location_id) REFERENCES locations(location_id));

INSERT INTO users(username)VALUES('user_1'),('user_2'),('user_3');
INSERT INTO locations("spatialPoint", name)VALUES(1,'location_1'), (2, 'location_2'), (3,'location_3');

INSERT INTO b_user_location(user_id, location_id)VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3);

SELECT
  b.user_id, 
  l.location_id,
  l."spatialPoint" AS distance
FROM  locations AS l
JOIN b_user_location AS b USING(location_id)
ORDER BY l."spatialPoint" ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

[/edit]

Comment: Sample data or SQLFiddle would be useful here.

Comment: Sql and sqlFiddle added, tnx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(location_id) * 
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON(b.user_id)
    b.user_id, 
    l.location_id,
    ROUND(distance(transform(PointFromText('POINT(4.0 52.0)', 4326), 26986),transform("spatialPoint", 26986))) AS distance
 FROM  locations AS l
    JOIN b_user_location AS b USING(location_id)
 ORDER BY ROUND(distance(transform(PointFromText('POINT(4.0 52.0)', 4326) ASC
)
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

It will give you 10 rows with both unique `user_id` and unique `location_id`, but these rows may not have the lowest `distance`.

Comment: Yeah it is close, but the order is required, I could wrap it in another subquery but I will have to see how this goes performance wise.